# Pandas: correct way to use apply() here?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that I am iterating over to perform a function, like this:

```
for time, row in dataframe.loc[symbol].itertuples():
    self.update(time, row.close)
```

I know that this is not the most efficient way, and that using **apply()** is faster.

However, as I need to access both **time** and **row** for my **update()** function, how would I be able to use **apply()** here?

I can create a function like this:

```
def update(time, row):
    self.update(time, row.close)
```

But the part where I call **apply()**, not sure how to do:

```
dataframe.apply(update, axis=?) --> Need access to time (index) here too
```

Because I need both index (time) and row value for this.

All examples I've seen don't need the index.

Comment: `axis='columns'` to access the whole row but what you need too is `groupby`. Take a while to read [Group by: split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html)

Comment: Can you provide an example input dataframe and the expected output? Iterating over rows it definitely not optimal and you should be able to increase speed using vectorized operation. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `dataframe.apply(lambda row: update(row.name, row.close), axis=1)`